# How is Nuxtjs started on openlitespeed with Nodejs? Startup file example

Tags: node.js, nuxtjs, openlitespeed

Trying to upload my project to openlitespeed. However, encountering difficulties.

Basic Node setup is that:

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World form node js app.js\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Have a look at how to include Modules as below:

```
var http = require('http');
var dt = require('./myfirstmodule');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write("The date and time are currently: " + dt.myDateTime());
  res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

But, I can basicly run my Nuxtjs project on local host.

What is the possible expected result:

Running Nuxtjs application on VPS which is upcloud with a startup file for having seen serving it on openlitespeed.

Have checked here, but no info on openlitespeeed deployment: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/deployment/nginx-proxy

Comment: Found a similar framwork (Starapi) run on OpenLiteSpeed guide, https://docs.litespeedtech.com/cloud/images/nodejs/#how-do-i-set-up-strapi hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks, have checked it already. The problem is that I can't make nuxtjs app start on litespeed. It starts from linux and it doesn't listen to started port and gives error "the port is already on use"

Comment: For inst: In order to run on node instead of npm run start, you will need some JavaScript. Execute the following to add a start.js script to the Strapi app folder:and there is a script to start strapi on Express. Would be great to have a script to start Nuxtjs just like Strapi starting script

Comment: Agree, but I'm not sure about the start script for NuxtJS too, let's see if other people know it.

Comment: Have found the solution. Use pm2, it is fine and consistent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi it was pretty easy after some research:

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/deployment/deployment-pm2

copy this file named ecosystem.config.js file in which it has these codes to Root folder of Nuxt:

```
module.exports = {
    apps: [
      {
        name: 'NuxtAppName',
        exec_mode: 'cluster',
        instances: 'max', // Or a number of instances
        script: './node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js',
        args: 'start'
      }
    ]
  }
```

Run on your linux:

```
killall node
cd /usr/local/lsws/serverclient/client
pm2 start
```

Good to go